# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.optimize'

Tags: python, installation, pip, scipy, scipy-optimize

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib import pyplot
```

The error I'm running into is this-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "H:/Hrishikesh1/best_fit.py", line 4, in <module>
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.optimize'
```

What can I do to fix this ?

Additional info - This was the output when I installed the scipy package using pip -

```
Installing collected packages: scipy
Successfully installed scipy-1.9.1
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -cipy 
(c:\users\workstation2\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site- 
packages)

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -cipy 
(c:\users\workstation2\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site- 
packages)

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -cipy 
(c:\users\workstation2\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site- 
packages)
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a test file with the first line of your code to see if I get the same error. I did not get the same error using python 3.9.12, numpy 1.23.1 and scipy 1.9.1. I also do not get the same warnings when installing scipy. This might be a problem related to a newer python version for which scipy is not compatible yet. However, I do not know why it doesn't work for you. I do know that these versions work.